# What is the bean configuration for datasource to connect to Oracle 11g

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, oracle11g, spring-jdbc

My DAO class is as follow

**EmployeeDAOImpl.java**

```
package com.shiladitya.emp.dao;

import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.shiladitya.emp.bean.Employee;

@Repository(value="empDAO")
public class EmployeeDAOImpl implements EmployeeDAO{

    @Autowired
    private DataSource ds;
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public DataSource getDs() {
        return ds;
    }
    public void setDs(DataSource ds) {
        this.ds = ds;
    }
    public JdbcTemplate getJdbcTemplate() {
        return jdbcTemplate;
    }
    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(this.getDs());
    }

    @Override
    public void createEmployeeTable() {
        String sql = "create table Employee (employeeId integer primary key, name varchar2(50), salary number(10,2));";
        jdbcTemplate.execute(sql);
    }

    @Override
    public void createEmployee(Employee employee) {
        String sql = "insert into Employee values(?,?,?)";
        jdbcTemplate.update(sql, new Object[] {employee.getEmployeeId(), employee.getName(), employee.getSalary()});
    }

    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    @Override
    public List<Employee> selectAllEmployee() {
        String sql = "select * from Employee";
        List<Employee> listOfEmployee = new ArrayList<Employee>();

        listOfEmployee  = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, new RowMapper(){
            public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException{
                Employee employee = new Employee();
                employee.setEmployeeId(rs.getInt("employeeId"));
                employee.setName(rs.getString("name"));
                employee.setSalary(rs.getDouble("salary"));

                return employee;
            }
        });

        return listOfEmployee;
    }

}
```

And below are the configuration file
**config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.shiladitya.emp" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"></bean>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"></property>
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"></property>
        <property name="username" value="system"></property>
        <property name="password" value="*******"></property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

And below are the main application where we create bean and use them

**UI.java**

```
package com.shiladitya.emp.ui;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

import com.shiladitya.emp.bean.Employee;
import com.shiladitya.emp.dao.EmployeeDAOImpl;

public class UI {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        @SuppressWarnings("resource")
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("config.xml");

        Employee employee = (Employee) context.getBean("employee");
        EmployeeDAOImpl edao = (EmployeeDAOImpl) context.getBean("empDAO");

        employee.setEmployeeId(1001);
        employee.setName("Shiladitya Kundu");
        employee.setSalary(24000.75);

        edao.createEmployeeTable();
        edao.createEmployee(employee);
    }

}
```

And I got an error like follow

**Error**

```
Jul 10, 2016 9:39:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@32c033: startup date [Sun Jul 10 21:39:00 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
Jul 10, 2016 9:39:00 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [config.xml]
Jul 10, 2016 9:39:00 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ds': Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'empDAO': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'ds': Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:350)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1214)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:775)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.shiladitya.emp.ui.UI.main(UI.java:13)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [config.xml]: Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:187)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1048)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1018)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:570)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1: org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property 'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    ... 27 more
```

Please provide me a solution how to connect to **Oracle 11g Express Edition** database using **jdbc thin driver** using bean property??

Please don't mark the question as duplicate as I was tried to search all relevent question to this but could't find any solution.

Comment: Error: *"Could not load JDBC driver class [oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver]"* Did you add the Oracle JDBC .jar file (e.g. `ojdbc6.jar`) to the classpath?

Comment: No, can u tell me where I'll get this jar??

Comment: Web search: [`oracle 11g jdbc`](https://www.google.com/search?q=oracle+11g+jdbc)

Comment: yeah now it;s working fine. thanks